# Mount Heavy TV onto re-patched drywall

Tags: drywall, mounting, drywall-anchor, patching-drywall, television

My contractor just installed our new 65 inch TV into our wall. The problem is it's about one inch too high. There are now 9 holes drilled into the wall, and only 2 holes is into wood. The rest is with plastic anchors into drywall. Would it be safe to remove these screws, patch the holes with wood filler, and remount the TV one inch below? The TV weighs 65 pounds and uses [Samsung's no gap wall mount](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-no-gap-tilting-tv-wall-mount-for-most-49-55-and-65-tvs-black/6348825.p?skuId=6348825).

Comment: most wall mounts provide several holes to allow for finer adjustment than just keep drilling holes in the wall. Well, for the ones I bought anyway.

Comment: If the contractor didn't put the mount where it was specified to go, can you get the contractor back to do the job correctly? Have him repair the drywall and remount - get what you paid for.

Comment: 9 holes seem...excessive. Especially with there only being 2 into studs on a 65 inch TV. Are your studs spaced 16" oc?

Comment: @SolarMike all mounts I've seen allow slight lateral adjustment, but not vertical adjustment

Comment: @mmathis the mount I have on the back of my tv has 3 vertical positions for the tv on it, so I planned to use the middle set and if my measurements were adrift or I wanted change I can move up or down by about an inch either way. Perhaps my mount was cheaper, or more expensive, who knows... And as for lateral adjustment it has a swivel arm so quite a bit there.

Comment: Why is the 3/4"  so important that you need to re-position it?

Comment: With a 65” only 2 lags hit studs , ? , wow   I would be making contact with more studs if your contact is only 2 screws at 1 end I would expect that to be sketchy when you have to tilt it to plug in new; Disk player,  cable  box ,video game console, or whatever.  If the contact is in the center it will probably be ok  but 9 and only 2 hit?

Comment: @FreeMan The contractor said it would be a lot of work to reposition it. I think he is referring to the work required to patch up the existing holes in a way that maintains the strength of the wall.

Comment: @mmathis The 2 studs are near the center and are vertically aligned.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I've edited the original post to one inch. The TV is positioned higher than eye level (due to furniture) and an additional inch would cause additional neck strain when watching.

Comment: @user4202 It still might be worth reconsidering your expectations. If you are sitting a reasonable distance away from a 65” tv, even a few inches shouldn’t matter. The general recommendation I have seen and used is to have the center of the tv at roughly 5 ft off the ground. This is above eye level for most people while seated and your eyes look up without having to crane your neck. No one in my family has ever complained of neck pain to date.

Comment: The contractor's job is to do what he was contracted to do. If he did it wrong the first time round, then he should be on the hook to do however much work is necessary to make it right, whether it's "a quick fix" or "a whole lot of work".

Comment: Would you come on back to give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or to write up (and check-mark) what you ended up doing to fix this? We'd all like to know...

Answer (score 1):

If there are two lag screws into studs near the top and these are far apart and other screws (7?) into drywall, then the TV sould be safely supported. I have not installed one of these. Does the mount extend from the wall and so exert pullout force on the fasteners?

Comment: The 2 studs are near the center and are vertically aligned. The TV uses the Samsung no gap wall mount. It does not extend from the wall and is nearly flush against it.

Comment: From your description this TV bracket is very well supported. I really don't  think it needs to be repositioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to move it. If the screw pattern is regular you may be able to get away with a few extra holes and be able to reuse some of the original holes.

One warning - Do not use wood filler to patch holes. It will not adhere correctly to drywall and not look good. Use a premixed joint compound if you want ease of use. For example: [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DRIcore-1-qt-PatchPro-Premixed-Patching-Compound-FG10023/205351518)

Use a suitable drywall anchor for the screws. Here is one that can hang 75lb each. [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/E-Z-Ancor-Twist-N-Lock-8-x-1-1-4-in-Phillips-White-Nylon-Flat-Head-75-Medium-Duty-Drywall-Anchors-with-Screws-20-Pack-25210/100140114)

Comment: I heard that wood filler was stronger to patch drywall screw holes. My main concern is the drywall would be weakened from the 9 previous holes 3/4 of an inch away from the new ones. The TV is heavy at 65 pounds and only has wood on 2 holes.

Comment: The drywall will likely be ok. If you use the right type of anchor and screw each screw should be able to hold up to 75lb. I will add a link to my answer. And use larger screws for two going into wood. If for some reason the drywall will give in you can replace a section of drywall going from stud to stud relatively easily. That would also allow you to install blocking (a cross beam of wood between the studs) where you need to hang the tv.

Comment: @user4202 I think you're correct to worry about new holes that close to existing holes in the drywall even with the proper wall anchors - it's a matter of the drywall giving way, not the anchor giving up. Are there more spots in the the mount that you can use to get lag bolts into studs instead of just drywall? Did you see the comment on the OP - are there adjustments available on the mount to move the TV without remounting it? Some come with slots so you can move the mount without making new holes.

Comment: I love those drywall anchors and use them quite often but they need good unbroken drywall to provide full strength with damaged material I would not trust them even at 1/2 the load and remember this will not be tight to the wall so there are lateral forces not just weight to think about.

Comment: @FreeMan Samsung's no gap wall mount is pretty limited in adjustments. I added the link to the original post. What is the best way to patch the drywall to mount the TV one inch below the current holes?

Comment: Why do you want to mount it one inch lower?